# How to restore /etc/sudoers, after making a mess and getting unable to use sudo?

Tags: sudo, system-recovery

I'm learning how to give `sudo` permission to different users.

At my first try editing `/etc/sudoers`, I made a syntax flaw and was unable to use `sudo`.

Whenever I would use `sudo` command, this message would appear:

> segmentation fault (cored dumped)

Comment: If this is a self answered question, please post the solution as an answer.

Comment: So, to edit `/etc/sudoers` always use `visudo` :)

Answer (score 2):

The thing is: you can't fix the syntax issue, without using `sudo visudo` to edit sudoers file. Hence, since I was unable to use `sudo`, I thought I would need to reinstall my OS, in order to fix the problem: which is not true!

All you got to do is:

1. reboot computer;
2. keep pressing `esc`;
3. run your linux distro in recovery mode;
4. once you're in recovery mode, you'll be able to access shell with root user without the need to use `sudo`;
5. edit sudoers file, as you would normally do: `visudo`.